# Падает wofstream поток при записи определенного символа

Tags: c++, c++14

Есть тестовый код:

```
void Check(std::wstring filePath)
{
    std::wofstream file;
    file.open(filePath, std::ios_base::app, _SH_DENYRD);

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            file << L"￥";
        }
        catch (std::wofstream::failure &ex)
        {
            printf_s(ex.what()); // Исключения нет
        }
        catch (std::exception &ex)
        {
            printf_s(ex.what()); // Исключения нет
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            printf_s("Exception"); // Исключения нет
        }

        if (!file.fail())
        {
            file.flush();
        }
        else
        {
            printf_s("Fail\n"); // выводится в консоль
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Проблему вызывает символ `￥`, почему такое происходит?

P.S. на аналогичном коде, написанном в C#, символ записывается корректно.

P.P.S. ОС: Windows, C++ 14, компилятор MS.

Comment: Посмотрите [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859020/windows-unicode-c-stream-output-failure). Там, кажется, решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @retorta, спасибо, сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу, уже разобрались, но на всякий случай...

Этот код пишет что угодно даже без `wstring`:

```
#include "stringf.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::string test = "￥";
    stringf::WriteBufferToFile("D:\\test.txt", test);
    return 0;
}
```

stringf.h:

```
#ifndef STRINGF_H
#define STRINGF_H
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
namespace stringf{
    unsigned long ReadFileToBuffer(std::string path, std::string &buffer, unsigned long position = 0){        
        unsigned long bytes_read = 0;
        HANDLE file = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
            buffer.resize(GetFileSize(file, NULL) - position);
            SetFilePointer(file, position, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
            ReadFile(file, &buffer[0], buffer.size(), &bytes_read, NULL);
            CloseHandle(file);
        }
        return bytes_read;
    }
    unsigned long WriteBufferToFile(std::string path, std::string buffer, bool append = false){
        unsigned long bytes_written = 0;
        unsigned long mode = append?OPEN_ALWAYS:CREATE_ALWAYS;
        HANDLE file = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, mode, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
            if (append){SetFilePointer(file, 0, NULL, FILE_END);}
            WriteFile(file, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size(), &bytes_written, NULL);
            CloseHandle(file);
        }
        return bytes_written;
    }
}
#endif /* STRINGF_H */
```